# why on running npm start, i get the error 'HOST' is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: javascript

I just installed NPM on my computer and I am trying to run it on cmd using `npm install` then `npm start`.

After running `npm start` this is what has come:

```
C:\Users\user2it\Downloads\pdfprocessingfrontend\pdfprocessingfrontend>npm start

> pdfprocessingfrontend@0.1.0 start
> HOST=127.0.0.1 react-scripts start

'HOST' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Because you're trying to run a script that assumed you'd be using macOS/Linux on Windows. I'd suggest using `cross-env` to set env vars in a more portable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following -

```
npm i cross-env
```

update the npm script to

```
cross-env HOST=127.0.0.1 react-scripts start
```